# line between radio button in css

Tags: html, css

I've made radio button like this : 
[image]
and I want to draw line between my radio button in css like this : 
[image]

I made my form look like this with table tag.

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_1">1</label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label for="answer_2">2</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_3">3</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_4">4</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_5">5</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_1" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_2" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_3" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_4" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_5" type="radio">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see the result here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/zpejzpw5/
How can I draw line between my radio button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code

```css
td {
  text-align: center
}
.line td {
  position: relative;
}
.line td:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.line td:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<span id="reponses">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="answer_1">1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="answer_2">2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="answer_3">3</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="answer_4">4</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label for="answer_5">5</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="line">
        <td>
          <input name="answer" id="answer_1" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="answer" id="answer_2" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="answer" id="answer_3" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="answer" id="answer_4" type="radio">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="answer" id="answer_5" type="radio">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</span>
```

Comment: With your z-index, pseudo element after disapear behind my table. And when I change the z-index to 0 my radio go behind the after element. How can I correct that?

Comment: I found : `radio{position:relative;z-index:1}`

Answer (score 6):

Using the `:after` pseudo element, you should be able to achieve this:

```css
td input {
  position: relative;
}
td input:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6px;
    background: #000;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    right: -12px;
}
td:last-child input:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_1">1</label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label for="answer_2">2</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_3">3</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_4">4</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="answer_5">5</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_1" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_2" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_3" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_4" type="radio">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="answer" id="answer_5" type="radio">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is that possible to change line with an arrow?

Comment: I didn't understand magic done in CSS, can you please clarify what made horizon line connecting 2 radio buttons ?