# Drawing a line behind range input

Tags: html, css, z-index, absolute

I'm trying to implement a Likert scale UI. I want to have the green line go behind the radio buttons. I tried changing the `z-index` but no luck...

```css
#container {    
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #ff5050;
    position: relative;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box {

  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>C</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>D</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>E</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>F</label>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems similar to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569681/line-between-radio-button-in-css

Comment: Just FYI, you may be interested to know there is an actual [range input type](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp) that may or may not make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` will only work along with `position`.

Adding `position` to your `input[type=radio]` will meet your requirement.

```css
#container {    
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #ff5050;
    position: relative;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}
input[type=radio] {
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box {

  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>C</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>D</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>E</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <label>F</label>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `z-index` will only apply to elements that have a `position`. As such, your `input` elements have no `z-index` applied to them, and resort to the default value of `0`.

It gets a little complicated with hierarchy, and `.box` is a **sibling** of `.line`. As such, all of your `.box` elements are of equal `z-index` to your line.

To have the line behind the notes, you'll want to use a value of `-1` for `.line`. Note that this will actually place the `.line` behind container, because that also defaults to `0`. As such, you'll additionally want to set a value of `-1` on `#container`.

Ultimately, you just need to ensure four things:

1. That `.line` has a `z-index` equal to or greater than `#container`
2. That `.box` has a higher `z-index` than `.line`
3. That `input` has a `z-index` equal to or greater than `.box`
4. That all elements with `z-index` also have a `position`

This can be seen in the following, which only sets a `-1` `z-index` on `#container` and `.line`:

```css
#container {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #ff5050;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    <label>A</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    <label>B</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    <label>C</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    <label>D</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    <label>E</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    <label>F</label>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)